# Permanent change of button color

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn Android Studio. Now I'm writing a simple app that would play sounds after pressing buttons (something like xylophone). 
Could you help me with the following problem ? I would like to change the color of the pressed button UNTIL next one is pressed (e.g. at first all buttons are red, pressed one changes its color to green and it is green until next button is pressed. 
I've already created xml files in drawable, that are responsible for changing the color of the button, WHEN it's pressed, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need a solution that will keep the button green until next button is pressed.

Here's my main_activity file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.adecostres.doremi.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_do"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:onClick="PlaySound_1"
                android:text="DO" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_re"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySound_1"
                android:text="RE" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_mi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:onClick="PlaySound_1"
                android:text="MI" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: how does your UI look?

Comment: Use `selector drawable` with proper states.

Comment: You have to change your button in the java file. what view are you using? ImageView, button? And how you are putting the colour? Background, src? If you put this information we can help more

Answer (score 2):

first of all create click listener function that handle all your button clicks then inside it write this code to iterate for each view in your layout and check for your button like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < your_layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = your_layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof Button){
            if (view.getId() == R.id.your_clicked_button_id){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
```

this will change all your button color to be red but your clicked button will be green

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

Maintain a global button object say "globalButton".

If any button presses(say "pressedButton"), then follow these steps

1. if(globalButton!=null) change globalButton to green
2. change pressedButton to red
3. globalButton=pressedButton

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the feedback. For now, I've come up with this solution (method in MainActivity.java, responsible for playing sound after pressing button:

```
public void PlaySound_1 (View v)
    {
        int sound = 0;
        dzwiek_do.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        dzwiek_re.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        dzwiek_mi.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        if (dzwiek_do.getId() == v.getId())
        {
            sound = sound_do;
            dzwiek_do.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        else if (dzwiek_re.getId() == v.getId())
        {
            sound = sound_re;
            dzwiek_re.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        else if (dzwiek_mi.getId() == v.getId())
        {
            sound = sound_mi;
            dzwiek_mi.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        playSound(this, sound);

    }
```